# how to select same column twice in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

Generally we can select a column in mongodb like follows,

```
db.TestData.find({"_id" : ObjectId("53eba30740adad086ce3599e")},{_id:1})
```

In sql we are selecting a same column twice like follows,

```
Select column1,column1 from table1
```

I need a mongodb query to select like above.
How can I do that?

thanks in advance. . . .

Answer (score 2):

You could either use a javascript function to manipulate it, or do a basic aggregate query using the [`project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) operator:

```
db.accounts.aggregate({ $project: { _id: 1, _id2: '$_id' }});

// Or using a match to filter the results first
db.accounts.aggregate(
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("53eba30740adad086ce3599e") } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, _id2: '$_id' } }
);
```